# Add borders to custom list web part

Tags: web-part, custom-list

Is it possible to put a border around cells in a custom list web part? If so, is it an easy change? I cannot find any settings that would change this look.

The default view doesn't have any borders at all. I require a custom list to look similar to the following:

[image: Sample table with borders]

Answer (score 1):

Google for CSS Selectors and target your Table and TH header to set color and borders.

Several places you can add your own style(sheet)

- Site Settings -> Masterpage (*if Publishing Features are enabled*)
- Editting the MasterPage with SP Designer *add a link to your own stylesheet*
- Site- Settings > Design Manager *Create a whole new Design*
- Inside a CEWP *but that will only get you the styles on the one page*
- Using a Browser Plugin (Chrome) Stylish *this changes anything in the page you want, but only in your browser*

Note: use the Browser Plugin for an easy start and get your CSS right